# What is the link between $\frac{1}{(1 + X^2)}$ and $e^{-X^2}$?

Tags: calculus

When I was playing with graphing, I realized that the shape of both $\frac{1}{(1 + X^2)}$ and $e^{-X^2}$ are very similar when plotted.

[graph of the first function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cobku.png)

[graph of the second function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fxah.png)

However, I can't seem to find any link between both of them, but vaguely remember that the former is a common result of a differential or an integral. So, out of curiosity, maybe someone might know it is?

Comment: You might be thinking of $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: It is a superficial resemblance.

Comment: 'shape' is not really a technical term. Even so, they have wildly different asymptotic behavior other than there limits tend to zero. $e^{-x^2}$ for example is in the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, whereas $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1 + X^2)}$ starts with $1 - X^2 + X^4 \dotsm$ and that of $e^{-X^2}$ starts with $1 - X^2 + \frac{1}{2}X^4 \dotsm$ This may explain the similarity of the shapes of the graphs of the two functions around $0$.

Comment: I understand that this question is somewhat superficial but I was looking for an answer that can explain it using a concept from a slightly different domain, and I think you nailed it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The power series for $e^z$ 
is $1+z+z^2/2+...$,
and the first two terms match
$1+z$.

From this,
the first two terms
of their reciprocals
also match:

$\dfrac1{1+z}
=1-z+z^2...$
and
$\dfrac1{e^z}
=e^{-z}
=1-z+z^2/2+...
$.

Finally,
putting $x^2$ for $z$,
we get
$\dfrac1{1+x^2}
=1-x^2+x^4...$
and
$\dfrac1{e^{x^2}}
=e^{-x^2}
=1-x^2+x^4/2+...
$,
so they differ for small $x$
by $x^4/2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!